# Span with number and floating text with same line-height

Tags: css, text

I have a text and there should be a number in a circle in front. It works but how can I vertical align the number within the circle? (padding makes the circle not even anymore) and
how is it possible to make the text "float" around the circle so it doesn't have a wrong line-height for the first line (all should be the same).

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 1.8em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ff922c;
  color: #ff922c;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="number">1</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam, accumsan
suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam dui nulla,
viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For infos, `display` can also do the trick without `line-height`.

[shape-outside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) can also be used so the text can go around it .

```css
.number {
  display: inline-flex;
  /* or flex, if it floats */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 1.8em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ff922c;
  color: #ff922c;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.number.bis {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

.number.bis.grid {
  display: grid;  /* for the show,but  a grid of a single cell really ? */
  shape-outside: circle(40%);
}
```

```html
<span class="number">1</span><code>Inline-flex</code> but <code>inline-grid</code> would be similar. dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam, accumsan
suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam dui nulla,
viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
<hr>
<span class="number bis ">1.1</span><code>Flex</code> & <code>float</code> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam, accumsan
suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam dui nulla,
viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
<hr>
<span class="number bis grid ">1.2</span><code>Grid</code> & <code>float</code> & <u><code>shape-outside</code></u> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam,
accumsan suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam
dui nulla, viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `display` of `.number` from `inline-block` to `inline-flex` and add `justify-content` and `align-items` properties. Value of both these properties should be `center`.

To fix the line-height, you could use `float`.

```css
.number {
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 1.8em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ff922c;
  color: #ff922c;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<span class="number">1</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam, accumsan
suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam dui nulla,
viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
```

Alternatively, you could use `::before` pseudo-element along with CSS counter

```css
body {
  counter-reset: myCounter;
}

span {
  counter-increment: myCounter;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

span::before {
  content: counter(myCounter);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ff922c;
  color: #ff922c;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam, accumsan
suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam dui nulla,
viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
</span>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam, accumsan
suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam dui nulla,
viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
</span>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam, accumsan
suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam dui nulla,
viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
</span>
```

Comment: Still has the odd gap this way

Comment: @j08691 Yes, i just noticed that. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float` to have the text float around the span and then set the line height to match the span height

```css
.number {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 1.8em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ff922c;
  color: #ff922c;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<span class="number">1</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id justo posuere ex pharetra euismod bibendum vel nunc. Donec pharetra ipsum sit amet augue ornare, non sodales leo dapibus. Nunc mollis sodales diam, accumsan
suscipit justo dignissim vitae. Nunc ultrices a elit nec hendrerit. Cras tempor elit quis nulla scelerisque aliquet. Nulla efficitur ac purus vitae porttitor. Morbi commodo efficitur ornare. Curabitur a ipsum dapibus erat iaculis finibus. Nullam dui nulla,
viverra id laoreet eget, fringilla ac orci. Nulla iaculis enim vitae dui congue accumsan. Fusce cursus justo non quam sodales blandit
```