# How to separate text from a circle

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a counter to make a white circle around a number. It has text next to it, the problem is that the circle it is over the text so it has no space in between. I tried using padding or margin but it doesn't work (i'm using bootstrap)

[image]

This is the HTML I am using

```
<div class="info col-sm-12">
    <h2 class="col-sm-12">¿Por qué elegir Egeria?</h2>
    <ol class="row">
        <li class="col-sm-3">
         <!--  <span class="circle">1</span> --> <span class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consectetur</span> adipiscing elit. Sed luctus.</li>
        <li class="col-sm-3">
           <!-- <span class="circle">2</span> --><span class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> consectetur </span>adipiscing elit. Sed luctus.</li>
        <li class="col-sm-3">
           <!-- <span class="circle">3</span>--> <span class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> consectetur </span>adipiscing elit. Sed luctus.</li>
        <li class="col-sm-3">
          <!--  <span class="circle">4</span>--> <span class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> consectetur </span>adipiscing elit. Sed luctus.</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
ol {
    margin-left:0; 
    padding-left:0; 
    counter-reset:item;
}

ol>li {
    margin-left:0; 
    padding-left:0; 
    counter-increment:item; 
    list-style:none inside;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

ol>li:before {
    content: counter(item);
    padding:8px 15px;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right:0.5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    color: #5960CB;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

I only want the text to not be so near to the white circle, thanks!

Comment: See if any of the code snippet in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63196234/6094348) helps. Second code snippet uses CSS counter.

Comment: @Yousaf it worked!! Thank you so much :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `line-height`, give it extra px if `25px` is not enough.

```
ol>li>span {
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

This is how it works. First `p` have `line-height` applied with the class `Special`.

```css
p.Special {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <p class="Special">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Your welcome! As this is the only answer of this question, please accept it.